# Using Galleria jQuery plugin with an asp.net ListView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, listview

I am trying to use [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se) with an asp.net ListView that gets the image sources from the database after those images are uploaded.  The following is my Listview :

```
        <div id="photoAlbumDiv" class="photoAlbumDiv">


        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" >
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                </td>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                </td>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">

                </td>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    <img id="photoAlbumPhotos" src='<%# Eval("img") %>' alt="Image Not Found" class="photoAlbumPhotos" />
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server" border="0" style="">
                    <tr ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                        <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="">
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <td runat="server" style="">
                    id:
                    <asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
                    <br />
                    img:
                    <asp:Label ID="imgLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("img") %>' />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </div>
```

and here is my jquery:

```
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        Galleria.loadTheme('Scripts/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
                        $("#photoAlbumDiv").galleria({
                            height: 1000,
                            width: 1000
                        });
                         </script>
```

Can it be done, thanks

Comment: Alison: How can you get the description displayed for each image?.Thanks

Comment: @shazia - you should find the answer here http://galleria.io/docs/references/data/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going about things the wrong way and making it more difficult than it needs to be.  The Galleria plugin expect HTML to be organized as follows:

```
<div>
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
    ...
    <img />
</div>
```

As you can see, there is nothing but images inside of a div.  You have a table structure which will not work.  Use the following code to run a quick sample and you'll see how easy it is.

**Javascript**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="galleria/galleria-1.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
        $("#gallery").galleria({
            width: 200,
            height: 300
        });
    });        
</script>
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvw">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="gallery">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img id="photoAlbumPhotos" src='<%# Eval("img") %>' alt="Image Not Found" class="photoAlbumPhotos" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lvw.DataSource = //Build datasource from database;
    lvw.DataBind();
}
```

And that's it.  You should have a simple Galleria gallery running in the browser.

Comment: but the whole point of using a listview is to retrieve the images from the database , and if i understood your code correctly i have to specify each image in the code behind

Comment: I hard-coded the image URLs because it would make it easy for you to run the sample code on your own machine and see how much better this solution is for you.  You can easily change the C# code to bind the ListView using data stored in a database. Ill update the question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: @Wahtever: I've updated the answer slightly to show that you can bind the ListView using data data from the database.  If you're using a SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource to bind the ListView then this code will still work exactly as is but you won't need to code-behind.  Update your question to let me know how you're binding the ListView.